# Question about Web Scraping - with Discord

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I want to create discord bot that will get some information through the Internet from google docs for example. I was searching a lot for any information about this problem but I could not find anything. I hope somebody will help me a bit with that issue. Thanks a lot to helpful people!

*i write it on python*

Comment: [Beutiful Soup](https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python/) should do what you need it to. Google docs/drive has an [API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api). Depending on what your exact use case is, [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/web-scraping-news-articles-in-python-9dd605799558) may be helpful. If you need this to work on arbitrary webpages without requiring manual work, I'm guessing [newspaper3k](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/newspaper-article-scraping-curation-python/) will work for more than just articles.

Comment: I'd give more specific information, but I don't have much experience with web scraping.